# How does one set Neo4j database in Neovis?

Tags: neovis

I have a Neo4j database that I'm trying to render in my webpage, but I need to select the database to be used, which is different from the URL.

I have a simple tag `<div id="viz"></div>` with the following JavaScript:

```
let config = {
    containerId: "viz",
    neo4j: {
        serverUrl: "neo4j://localhost:7687",
        serverUser: "neo4j",
        serverPassword: "*****",
    },
    initialCypher: "MATCH (n) RETURN n"
}
this.neo4j = new Neovis(config);
this.neo4j.render();
```

I tried adding `database` to the `neo4j` section and adding the name of the database in the `serverUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For anyone who may refer to this in the future, the property `serverDatabase` needs to be added outside of the `neo4j` section like so:

```
let config = {
    containerId: "viz",
    neo4j: {
        serverUrl: "neo4j://localhost:7687",
        serverUser: "neo4j",
        serverPassword: "*****",
    },
    serverDatabase: "dbname",
    initialCypher: "MATCH (n) RETURN n"
}
```